# How to solve this problem for hierarchical data structure?

Tags: index, mariadb, unique-constraint

I have this table called `Hierarchies`. This is its actual definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `Hierarchies` (
  `Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Guid` uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid(),
  `Key` varchar(400) NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid(),
  `Slug` varchar(400) NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid(),
  `Order` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `EntityTypeGuid` uuid NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  `ImageGuid` uuid DEFAULT NULL,
  `IconGuid` uuid DEFAULT NULL,
  `IconSvg` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ParentId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IsActive` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ItemsCount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Level` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IsLeaf` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IX_Hierarchies_Unique_Guid` (`Guid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IX_Hierarchies_Unique_Key` (`Key`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IX_Hierarchies_Unique_Slug` (`Slug`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IX_Hierarchies_Unique_EntityTypeGuid_And_ParentId_And_Title` (`EntityTypeGuid`,`ParentId`,`Title`),
  KEY `FK_Hierarchies_ParentId_Hierarchies_Id` (`ParentId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Hierarchies_ParentId_Hierarchies_Id` FOREIGN KEY (`ParentId`) REFERENCES `Hierarchies` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `Ck_Hierarchies_NonEmptyGuid` CHECK (`Guid` <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
  CONSTRAINT `Ck_Hierarchies_NonEmptyEntityTypeGuid` CHECK (`EntityTypeGuid` <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
  CONSTRAINT `Ck_Hierarchies_NonEmptyImageGuid` CHECK (`ImageGuid` <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
  CONSTRAINT `Ck_Hierarchies_NonEmptyIconGuid` CHECK (`IconGuid` <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

And I want to **have unique titles, per entity type and per parent**.

`UNIQUE KEY 'IX_Hierarchies_Unique_EntityTypeGuid_And_ParentId_And_Title' ('EntityTypeGuid','ParentId','Title')`

And it works fine for all child records that have `ParentId`. But for root nodes, the records that do not have `ParentId` and their `ParentId` value is `NULL`, this does not work.

That's because MariaDB does not include `NULL` values for the index.

What can I do?

Comment: All NULLs are unique - this is a base.

If you want NULLs to be treated as definite value and does not allow more than one NULL then you'd replace it with some definite but impossible value. For example this can be `CHAR(0)` for string-type columns (EntityTypeGuid,Title), and zero (or -1) for numeric columns (ParentId).

Depends on DBMS version you may use according generated columns and unique index by them, or index by function.

Comment: FIrst explain what `EntityTypeGuid` is for and where it comes form.

Comment: 5 unique keys is "unreasonable" for a table.  I don't think I have ever seen a "reasonable" table with more than 2 unique keys.

Comment: I hope that you don't have more than a few million rows; GUIDs are costly to handle due to their randomness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make top entries in your hierarchy reference a root node (e.g. with ID 0) in `ParentId`. This includes them in the index. The drawback is that you now need to include `… AND Id <> 0` when querying the hierarchy.